# What is recordSetVar and where is it used?

Tags: visualforce

I was looking at some code and in the 'apex:page' tag, an attribute called recordSetVar was mentioned. I'm new to VisualForce so could someone please tell me when and why is it used?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main difference between using `recordSetVar` or not boils down to the underlying Apex class that your page will use.

First of all you have to use it with the `standardController` attribute. Using that attribute tells your page that it is using a particular kind of data. Either one of the standard Salesforce objects like `Account` or `Contact`, or perhaps your own custom entity, `Progress_Report__c`, for instance. The behavior of the page will be to instantiate an Apex class called `StandardController`. If the URL of the `GET` request that requested your page includes a value in its `id` parameter, that value will be used to query for the actual record and it will be instantiated. If no value, you get an empty instance of the record class.

So what happens when you add the `recordSetVar` attribute? For instance this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Car__c" recordSetVar="cars">
```

First of all the underlying Apex class representation of your data changes to `StandardSetController`. This class presents a list of data. The list will be of the type indicated in the `standardController` attribute and the variable name for the list is the value of `recordSetVar`, in this instance `cars`.

Next, at runtime the query will no longer use an `id` attribute, but will default to the *last used List View* the user has used.

Finally `StandardSetController` has methods for accessing and changing the list data, and a couple of special attributes related to List Views. These are all documented in the Visualforce [guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm).

If you're thinking to yourself, "hmmmm...can I instantiate those classes myself?" Then give yourself a pat on the back. It is common (although often overlooked, I think), that for the purposes of basic CRUD and built-in list functionality, you can instantiate either `StandardController` or `StandardSetController` in any Apex class that uses Visualforce and then leverage the methods and properties they surface in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

The recordSetVar attribute indicates that the page uses a list controller, it can indicates the variable name of the record collection. This variable can be used to access data in the record collection.

for example,

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >

    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="a" >
        <apex:column value="{!a.Id}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Yeah, but when do you use it? You can run the above code even if you do not have the recordSetVar attribute in it.

Comment: By default recordSetVar includes all the records for the object in your org. This record set can be used in the expressions to return values to display on the page or to perform actions on set of records. So when your using standard controller you can use recSetVar to retrieve all the records for the object.

Comment: If my answer is helped you. Mark it as answer to help community. Thanks!