# Use the Salesforce Lightning Design System to Style Visualforce Pages Issue

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, slds

Working through the Visualforce Mobile module

I want to do an exercise (3rd unit) that consists of displaying the contacts their names and phone numbers.

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" standardController="Contact" recordSetVar="contacts">
<head>
<apex:slds />
</head>
<apex:repeat value="{!contacts}" var="c">
    <dl class="slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap">
        <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Contact Name:">{!c.Name}</dt>
        <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Mobile Phone Number:">{!c.Phone}</dd>
    </dl>
</apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

I tried this code,I have no errors, however the list of contacts is not displayed!
I tried to display a simple text it works, so the problem is at the level of the apex repeat I think

Comment: You are using `recordSetVar` but you have not specified any list to iterate? there is no custom controller. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97423/what-is-recordsetvar-and-where-is-it-used

Comment: @PranayJaiswal value="{!contacts}"

Comment: @PranayJaiswal This is a valid syntax for recordSetVar.

Comment: I tried this in my developer org, your code works just fine copy-pasted. Consider setting up a [debug log](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_add_users_debug_log.htm&type=5) and see if you show any errors there.

Comment: @sfdcfox all debug log success everywhere but the list still does not show up