# #Visualforce #apex:pageBlockTable

Tags: visualforce

I am novice in Visualforce . I am learning few tags . I have used following code to display a list of Accounts in a tabular format in VF page. My expectations was all i get is list of atleast 20 records or all Accounts. But i am getting only 2 records which are just newly created by while learning VF. Please help me .Following is code

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts" >
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="All Accounts across Org">
        <apex:pageBlockTable  value="{!accounts}" var="a">
            <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.AccountNumber}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.Website}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.Type}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have more than 2 accounts? There is nothing wrong with that VF page.

Comment: yes Carlos.There are 23 Acounts

Comment: What are the Sharing Settings set for Accounts? Public? Private? Are you the owner of all those accounts?

Comment: i am owner of all Accounts  , Profile is System Admin  .Also i have tested on Contact object ,its working fine

Comment: According to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97423/what-is-recordsetvar-and-where-is-it-used), your recordsetvar defaults to the last used List View the user has used.  Create an "All" list view, view it, and then try your page.

Comment: Thanks David it did worked